# Is there a way to failover messages in a distributed ActiveMQ cluster?

Tags: messaging, activemq-classic

In a distributed activemq cluster, if a node fails, its messages are lost until it comes back. Is there a way to keep distributing these messages even if a node fails ?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you do this using a shared message store and having multiple brokers use that store. Only one of these brokers will be active at any time  - the one that connected to the store first. This is managed via locks. When the active broker falls over the second broker will pick up the lock and it then becomes active, handling any messages in the store that were not sent by the first broker. Clients (producers and consumers) connect to the broker pair via the connection string

```
failover:(tcp://broker1Host:broker1Port,tcp://broker2Host:broker2port)
```

Only the broker that holds the lock will accept connections, so the failover string specifies that the client should attempt to connect to the next broker in the list. Using this mechanism it is even possible to have multiple slaves waiting to take over if the master fails.

You can find more information about this at http://activemq.apache.org/shared-file-system-master-slave.html if you have access to a network file system that supports locks (such as a SAN, or NFS), or if not you can use a database as your message store http://activemq.apache.org/jdbc-master-slave.html

Comment: From our experience with the jdbc-active-passive, the failover nonetheless loses a handful of non-persistent messages. So the next question would be, is there a way to anticipate a broker switch and not lose the in-limbo non-persistent messages ?

Answer (score 0):

Do you want the `master-slave` ha?
http://activemq.apache.org/masterslave.html

> The problem with running lots of stand alone brokers or brokers in a
>   network is that messages are owned by a single physical broker at any
>   point in time. If that broker goes down, you have to wait for it to be
>   restarted before the message can be delivered. (If you are using
>   non-persistent messaging and a broker goes down you generally lose
>   your message).
>
> The idea behind MasterSlave is that messages are replicated to a slave
>   broker so that even if you have catastrophic hardware failure of the
>   master's machine, file system or data centre, you get immediate
>   failover to the slave with no message loss.

More here: http://activemq.apache.org/replicated-message-store.html

Comment: This is what i use at the moment, but i'd like to use a distributed cluster and the blocking point is the lost of messages

Comment: I don't understand. Do you already use the message replication or just several brokers?

Answer (score 0):

create a broker network where every broker has a slave (for example with direct replication).
this way if the master fails the slave can join the broker network and take the position of its former master. depending on your chosen replication scheme the former master broker might even recover and rejoin the new master as a slave node.

for example: [direct replication](http://activemq.apache.org/pure-master-slave.html) within a [network of brokers](http://activemq.apache.org/networks-of-brokers.html)

As far as i know its not possible to "force" activemq to store pending messages redundantly on several brokers.